# Error Handling ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a global error handling for the controller which is working fine. But sometimes when any web.config element are missing or can't able to load it shows the error screen and hitting the application-error in the global.asax as the the exception never reaches the pipe line. Also I was able to redirect to a custom error page by setting custom error as remoteonly with redirection page but not able to log it as not hitting application-error in global.asax. Does anyone know how to handle the exception here

Comment: Can you post some code to help us understand your problem?

Answer (score -1):

I guess, Exception handles your code only, the exception which you were taking is before any code to be execute and it will handle by Web Server i.e. IIS